# Start of DHCP Client without any DHCP server delays the start of other services for a long time

Tags: debian, systemd, raspberry-pi, dhcp

On Bullseye (Debian) I have this in /var/log/syslog when no DHCP server is present on the network.

```
Jul 10 10:45:05 localhost systemd[1]: Started DHCP Client Daemon.
Jul 10 10:45:05 localhost dhcpcd[372]: forked to background, child pid 757
Jul 10 10:45:23 localhost systemd[1]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Succeeded.
Jul 10 10:46:33 localhost systemd[1]: connman-wait-online.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=110/n/a
Jul 10 10:46:34 localhost systemd[1]: connman-wait-online.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 10 10:46:34 localhost systemd[1]: Failed to start Wait for network to be configured by ConnMan.
Jul 10 10:46:34 localhost systemd[1]: Reached target Network is Online.
Jul 10 10:46:34 localhost systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Prepares and starts codesyscontrol...
```

In this case we see the line "forked to background, child pid 757" why? And why does it because of that take so long time before other systemd processes are started. Especially codesyscontrol as seen.

Answer (score 0):

That's how DHCP works. The client sends out a broadcast packet, saying "What's my IP? My MAC is <48-bit MAC>", and expects somebody to respond with all that DHCP goodness. On timeout (your case), the client sends the packet again, and waits. After about 5 timeouts, with increasing wait times, the client gives up, doesn't obtain an IP address,  and startup continues.

Either don't run `dhclient` if there's no DHCP server on the LAN, or read `man dhclient` (and the See Also `man` pages) to see if you can adjust the configuration.

Comment: You miss the problem. The fact it doesn't get the IP address should not means it delays the initialization of other processes for >20seconds. "forked to background, child pid 757" means that the DHCP client should work in the background and the system should immediately proceed with the many other things it has to do after boot. I have another device with Buster without any delay, but here the client is started differently.